# PHP Function Help

Tags: php, moodle

I've written this piece of code, which outputs the `profile_display_fields` for the $USER:

```
$appearance = profile_display_fields($USER->id);
        if (empty($appearance)) {
            //Do nothing
        } else {
            foreach ($appearance as $c) {
            $custom .= '<a href=\''.$CFG->wwwroot.'/course/view.php?id='.$c->id.'\'>'.$c->fullname.'</a>';
            }
        }
```

Here is the function I'm using:

```
function profile_display_fields($userid) {
    global $CFG, $USER;

    if ($categories = get_records_select('user_info_category', '', 'sortorder ASC')) {
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            if ($fields = get_records_select('user_info_field', "categoryid=$category->id", 'sortorder ASC')) {
                foreach ($fields as $field) {
                    require_once($CFG->dirroot.'/user/profile/field/'.$field->datatype.'/field.class.php');
                    $newfield = 'profile_field_'.$field->datatype;
                    $formfield = new $newfield($field->id, $userid);
                    if ($formfield->is_visible() and !$formfield->is_empty()) {
                        print_row(s($formfield->field->name.':'), $formfield->display_data());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm looking to do is try some `var_dump`s to output the correct data.

However can anyone help me identify the variables?

Comment: what do you want to var_dump? which variable?

Comment: I know var_dump($something); but which are the variables in the PHP above?

Comment: As you have written the code, you should know the `$something` s are variables...

Answer (score 1):

In your function you are not returning any value but above that in your code, you have assigned a variable to this function:

```
$appearance = profile_display_fields($USER->id);
```

You need to return some variable/data from the function and *that is the one to be var dumped*.

I suppose you are using the `print_row` to **print** the data, not returning the response to be used out of the function.